# Is it better to collect all apps in one app or divide them into partial apps?

Tags: android, kotlin, development-environment, android-developer-api

I am creating an android application to run an educational institution.

Is it better to separate the application for the manager, the application for the teachers, and the application for the students (each application alone), or is it better to have one application through which the login is made to the part of the manager, the part of the teacher, or the part of the student?

3 applications

Manager app
Professors private app
Student application

Answer (score 2):

the admin part could just be separate and it would make more sense. Only one app can be used for teacher and student.

It is important that the administrator application is separate, it will be more secure as it is an application that only the administrator can enter. And since the admin panel will be different compared to other pages, you will have to make different page designs.